# JdbcTemplate how to auto generate primary key

Tags: java, sql, spring, hsqldb, jdbctemplate

I'm using spring and it's JdbcTemplate for DB connection and I am trying to auto generate a key for my primary key column. I am also using `HSQLDB`. The table looks like that:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Customers (
    cid BIGINT GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    ...
);
```

The code in my Dao object looks like that:

```
Map<String, Object> values = new HashMap<String, Object>();
values.put("name", customer.getName()); 
// NOT putting the cid
...
SimpleJdbcInsert insert = new SimpleJdbcInsert(jdbc).withTableName(
                "CUSTOMERS").usingGeneratedKeyColumns("CID");
Long key = (Long) insert.executeAndReturnKey(values);
```

As you can see, I am not putting the key manually and I expect that the `usingGeneratedKeyColumns` method will generate it automatically for me. Anyways I get this error after executing `executeAndReturnKey` :

`org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: PreparedStatementCallback; SQL    []; integrity constraint violation: NOT NULL check constraint; SYS_PK_10094 table: CUSTOMERS column: CID; nested exception is java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: integrity constraint violation: NOT NULL check constraint; SYS_PK_10094 table: CUSTOMERS column: CID`

Comment: why would you do that? just let your db generate the key using autoincrement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the auto generation of keys from `HSQLDB` has a slightly different syntax. You need to define it as an `IDENTITY` and then as a `PRIMARY KEY`:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Customers (
    cid BIGINT GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    ...
);
```